# Load JS file into DOM without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-developer-toolbar

I have a piece of JS code which I want to load into a third-party website (via chrome DOM). How do I go about this **without using jQuery** (the page has blocked the import of any js libraries)?

Comment: not sure how a site blocks javascript libraries....  how are you adding this code? console? document.createElement.....

Comment: out of curiosity, how do you perceive doing this with jQuery?

Comment: This does not make any sense. You want to inject your JS Code into a 3rd party website? Are you using GreaseMonkey or something? Otherwise what you're doing is considered cross site scripting or JavaScript injection.

Answer (score 1):

```
var script=document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
script.setAttribute("src", "http://www.example.com/your/script");
document.body.appendChild(script);
```